# 引数で値の受け渡し（２）

Tags: c#

引数受け渡しの練習をし、次にDBから受け取った値を表示しようとしています。DB接続・値取得クラスを作成し、表示するクラスも作成しました。が、この場合はどう引数を使えば良いですか？、、何かアドバイスをください。。。

（DBConnectionクラス）

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        string words;
        string con;
        con = "Server = localhost; Port = 5432; User Id = postgres; Password = Password; Database = voc";
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(con);
        conn.Open();
        var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(@"select * from t_voc", conn);
        try
        {

            NpgsqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    words = dataReader[i].ToString();
                    return words;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var ArgumentException = new ArgumentException();

        }

        conn.Close();
```

（表示クラス）

```
public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static void StartButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //まだ途中ですが、ここがとてもややこしいです
      string words = MainForm.

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

おそらく理想としては以下のような形式なのだと推測しますが、

```
// 戻り値として使用する型
class Row
{
    // 必要な列を定義する
    public string ColumnName1 { get; set; }
    public int ColumnName2 { get; set; }
    public bool ColumnName3 { get; set; }
}

class DBConnection : IDisposable // このクラス名はDbConnectionと被っているので変更をお勧めします
{
    // ローカル変数から移動
    NpgsqlConnection conn;

    // ローカル変数conからプロパティに変更
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        // ConnectionStringの初期値 (設定ファイルから取得するべき)
        = "Server = localhost; Port = 5432; User Id = postgres; Password = Password; Database = voc";

    // メソッドは以下のように変更する
    // public static void Main()
    public List<Row> GetData()
    {
        // 複数行を想定しているのであれば、リストを使用する
        // string words;
        List<Row> list = new List<Row>();

        // インスタンスへ移動
        // string con;
        // con = "Server = localhost; Port = 5432; User Id = postgres; Password = Password; Database = voc";

        // インスタンス化しているので初回のみ接続を開始する。
        //NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(con);
        if (conn == null)
        {
            conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnectionString);

            // 例外処理はこちらに移動する。
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("接続の開始中に例外が発生しました。", e);
            }
        }
        var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(@"select * from t_voc", conn);

        // conn.Open()へ移動
        //try
        //{

        NpgsqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            // 一行ごとに値を取り出して設定する
            //for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
            //{
            //    words = dataReader[i].ToString();
            //    return words;
            //}
            var row = new Row();
            row.ColumnName1 = dataReader.GetString(1);
            row.ColumnName2 = dataReader.GetInt32(4);
            row.ColumnName3 = dataReader.GetBoolean(9);

            // 行を戻り値のリストに追加する。
            list.Add(row);
        }

        // conn.Open()へ移動
        //}
        //catch (Exception e)
        //{
        //    var ArgumentException = new ArgumentException();

        //}

        // クローズは1度だけ行う
        // conn.Close();

        // 最後に戻り値を返す。
        return list;
    }

    // 共通クローズ処理
    public void Dispose()
    {
        conn?.Dispose();
        conn = null;
    }
}

// 表示側
private static void StartButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // usingで確実にDisposeを行う
    using (var c = new DBConnection())
    {
        // データの受け渡し方
        c.ConnectionString = ...;
        var data = c.GetData();
        textBox1.Text = data[0].ColumnName1;
    }
}
```

上記の通り修正点は多数あるので、まずは簡便な`NpgsqlDataAdapter`+`DataTable`などでデータアクセスについて学ばれた方が良いのではないかと思います。